# Get result from success handler

Tags: javascript

I am listing game in my application. Some are paid and some are free so during listing I am calling a method to get price from play store and response getting in Success callback. My problem is my success handler setting price after listing all games so all games are listed as free. My code is

**Listing game**

```
function render(res)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        var data=res[i];
        if(data.product_id!='Free' && data.product_id!='')
        {
            getDetails(data.product_id);
        }
        else
        {
            price='Free';
        }
        console.log(price);
        var gameOnScreen = "<li class='game-box showlist'  data-tag='" + app_tag + "' >" +
        "<div class='game-box-link' data-id='" + game.ID + "' data-orientation='" + orientation + "' data-ajax='false' data-url='" + link + "' data-transition='none'>" +
        "<img src='" + thumb + "' class='game-thumb'>" +price+
        "</div></li>";
        }
    }
}
```

**Get Detail**

```
function getDetails(productlist)
{
    inappbilling.getProductDetails(successHandler2, errorHandler, productlist);
}
```

**successHandler2**

```
function successHandler2 (result)
{
    price= result[0].price;
    console.log(price);
}
```

[image]

In image you can see price is coming after listing all games.

Comment: I think you need to give callback.

Comment: where to give callback?

Comment: Please show getProductDetails,I need to check how you returning the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just rewrote your code as a recursive call:

```
function render(res)
 {

    var length = res.length;
    var i=0;
    var price;

    function display(){
     var gameOnScreen = "<li class='game-box showlist'  data-tag='" + app_tag + "' >" +
            "<div class='game-box-link' data-id='" + game.ID + "' data-orientation='" + orientation + "' data-ajax='false' data-url='" + link + "' data-transition='none'>" +
            "<img src='" + thumb + "' class='game-thumb'>" +price+
            "</div></li>";
     i++;//incrementing to nextitem, but not triggering next iteration as a loop.
    };
    function getDetails()
    {
            if(res[i].product_id!='Free' && res[i].product_id!='')
            {
                inappbilling.getProductDetails(successHandler2, errorHandler, res[i].product_id);
            }
            else
            {
                price='Free';
                display();//displaying item
            }

    };
    function successHandler2 (result)
    {
        price= result[0].price;
        console.log(price);
        display();//displaying current item
        if(i<length){
            getDetails();//after getting current item's price go for next
        }
    };
    getDetails();//initial call

}
```

This will step over to next item after completing current item.
Also note that I didn't take care of `errorHandler`

Comment: That's a bit inefficient. You'd be better off abstracting the asynchronous flow to something like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) so you can take advantage of parallel processing and get your results faster.

Answer (score 0):

Add a callback to `getDetails()` like this:

```
function getDetails(productlist, callback)
{
    inappbilling.getProductDetails(function successHandler2(result) {
        callback(result[0].price);
    }, errorHandler, productlist);
}
```

Now you can work with the price where you call `getDetails()`:

```
getDetails(res.product_id, function callback(price) {
    // now you can update the DOM to show the actual price.
});
```

However, I would only show a game in the list after the price has been retrieved (add it to the DOM in the callback). Otherwise it will appear as free for a short time.

Comment: i don't think so this will solve my problem.
for loop of `render()`  is completing before getting response from `getDetails()`

Comment: Yes, that's why I wrote that I would rather show the games after the prices have been received. My solution just illustrates how to get the price value out of the getDetails() function.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that all HTML are rendered, use product ID as an class/id or HTML attribute to distinguish different products.

```
<li class='game-box showlist'  data-productid='productId' >
    ...
</li>
```

Then, call `getProductDetails`, pass in the HTML selector which point to the product. You can use it to update the HTML after the success callback return, something like this:

```
function getDetails(productlist, selector)
{
    inappbilling.getProductDetails(function(result) {
        var price= result[0].price;
        $(selector).html(price);
    }, errorHandler, productlist);
}
```

Notice that instead of setting default price to 'free', you might want to use another place holder.